# Compare memusage in tasklist (DOS)

Tags: batch-file

I have to find the biggest program's PID (biggest memory usage) in DOS.
I found how to browse the programs using tasklist, I have the memory they use ('2 402 Ko'), but I can't sort them with this, it's not a number (spaces, "Ko", ...).

```
for /F "tokens=2,5 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /NH /FO CSV') do (
    echo %%a size %%b
)
```

How can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a biggest=0
set "proc_name="
rem :: be careful here .You need two spaces before %%a
for /F tokens^=1^,4^,5^,6^ delims^=^"^,^  %%a in ('tasklist /NH /FO CSV') do (

 set /a biggest_candidate=%%c%%d

 if !biggest_candidate! GTR !biggest! (
    set /a biggest=%%c%%d
    set "proc_name=%%a"
 )
)

echo !biggest! -- !proc_name!

endlocal
```